# Can I add multiple itemscope in Microdata?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I' m trying to add microdata on my website but i meet difficulties.

on an categorie page of a wordpress I'm trying to add multiple http://schema.org/BlogPosting

- one for the content and description of the category
- and one of each article summary

But and I check on https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool
I everytime get a problem to add publisher.
**But as is always the same I guess I should have to redefine each time?
so how can I add reference?**

Or do I follow a wrong way by trying to add multiple itemscope?

```
<body>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blogposting">
    <header role="banner" id="headertop" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization" itemprop="publisher" itemref="blockfanfb mypaqe_footer">
        <div  itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
            <a id="header_logo" href="http://www.mywebsite/" title="mywebsite"><img itemprop="url" src="http://www.mywebsite/img/logo-4.jpg" alt="mywebsite" width="130" height="68"/></a>
            <meta itemprop="width" content="130">
            <meta itemprop="height" content="68">
            <a href="http://www.mywebsite/" title="mywebsite" itemprop="name" > MYWEBSITE</a>
        </div>
        <nav itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
            <span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
                <a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="http://www.mywebsite/">
                <span itemprop="name">My site</span></a>
                <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
            </span> › 
            […]
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main">
        <article id="container" itemprop="articleBody">
            <meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage"  itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="http://mywebsite.com/blog/cat/"/>
              <header class="iframe-responsive-wrapper">
                <h1 itemprop="headline" class="page-title">Nvel catégorie</h1>
                <p itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">By <span itemprop="name">Me</span></p>
                <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2016-11-24T13:01:32+00:00">2016-11-24T13:01:32+00:00</time>
                <time class="updated" itemprop="dateModified"  datetime="2016-11-24T13:56:51+00:00">2016-11-24T13:56:51+00:00</time>
            </header>
        <div>
            <div class="category-description">
                <p>test</p>
                <div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                    <img src="http://mywebsite.com/image.jpg" />
                    <meta itemprop="url" content="http://mywebsite.com/image.jpg">
                    <meta itemprop="width" content="1024">
                    <meta itemprop="height" content="1365">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <footer>
    <hr>
    Other article
    <hr>
    <section>
        <!-- ARTICLE 1 -->
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
            <meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage"  itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="http://mywebsite.com/cat/article1/"/>
            <meta itemprop="publisher" itemref="headertop blockfanfb mypaqe_footer">
            <h3 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="http://mywebsite.com/blog/new/image-en-direct-extrait-et-headline/" title="ARTICLE" itempropp="url" rel="bookmark">ARTICLE</a></h3>
            <div>
                <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2016-11-24T13:01:32+00:00">2016-11-24T13:01:32+00:00</time>
                <time class="updated" itemprop="dateModified"  datetime="2016-11-24T13:56:51+00:00">2016-11-24T13:56:51+00:00</time>
            </div>
            <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">By <a href="https://plus.google.com/+Me?rel=author" rel="nofollow"><span itemprop="name">ME</span></a></span>
            <div  class="image-article-list" itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <img width="150" height="150" src="http://mywebsite.com/image.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" /
                <meta itemprop="url" content="http://mywebsite.com/image.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="150">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="150">
            </div>
            <div class="resume-article-list">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [~]</div>     </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ARTICLE 2 -->
        <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
            <meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage"  itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="http://mywebsite.com/cat/article1/"/>
            <meta itemprop="publisher" itemref="headertop blockfanfb mypaqe_footer">
            <h3 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="http://mywebsite.com/blog/new/image-en-direct-extrait-et-headline/" title="ARTICLE2" itempropp="url" rel="bookmark">ARTICLE2</a></h3>
            <div>

                <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2016-11-24T13:01:32+00:00">2016-11-24T13:01:32+00:00</time>
                <time class="updated" itemprop="dateModified"  datetime="2016-11-24T13:56:51+00:00">2016-11-24T13:56:51+00:00</time>
            </div>
            <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">By <a href="https://plus.google.com/+Me?rel=author" rel="nofollow"><span itemprop="name">ME</span></a></span>
            <div  class="image-article-list" itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <img width="150" height="150" src="http://mywebsite.com/image.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" /
                <meta itemprop="url" content="http://mywebsite.com/image.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="150">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="150">
            </div>
            <div class="resume-article-list">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [~]</div>     </div>
        </div>

    </section>

        </footer>

</article>
    </main>
    <footer role="contentinfo">
        […]
        <div id="mypaqe_footer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Corporation">
            À propos de <span itemprop="name">mywebsite</span>
            <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.mywebsite">
            <p itemprop="description">blla bla <time itemprop="foundingDate" datetime="2013-01-01">2013</time> par l'<span itemprop="founders">me</span></p><br />
            Contact<br />
            <p id="contact">
                <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                    <span itemprop="streetAddress">2405 street</span><br />
                    <span itemprop="postalCode">9999</span>
                    <span itemprop="addressLocality">bépo</span>,<br />
                    <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="FR" />France
                </span><br />
                <span id="contact" itemprop="contactPoint" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPoint">
                <a href="mailto:contact@mywebsite" itemprop="email">contact@mywebsite</a><br />
                <meta itemprop="contactType" content="customer support">
                Tel:<span itemprop="telephone">+33-9-12341234</span>,<span id="drapeau" class="sprite"></span>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="blockfanfb">
                <div id="fb-root"></div>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/me/123412342596423"> </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="sprite" href="http://twitter.com/#!/mywebsite/"></a>
                <a class="sprite" href="http://pinterest.com/mywebsite/"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### How to use Microdata’s `itemref`

The way you use `itemref` is not correct.

You have to specify the `itemprop` on the element you want to reference, not on the element that references.

So the structure could look like this:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemref="corp">
</article>

<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemref="corp">
</article>

<div id="corp" itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Corporation">
</div>
```

(I assume that the items `Corporation` and `Organization` are about the same entity in your case. If that’s true, you shouldn’t have both.)

#### Notes about your use of Schema.org

It’s not correct to use the `BlogPosting` type for a category in a blog.

I think in your case it makes sense to use [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage), which also allows you to add your `BreadcrumbList` via the [`breadcrumb`](http://schema.org/breadcrumb) property.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CollectionPage">

  <nav itemprop="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  </nav>

</div>
```

Each blog post could be added via [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart), or you could add an [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) as [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) of the `CollectionPage`.

Comment: thanks a lot @unor, that's what i was looking for.

About your second part: "Notes about your use of Schema.org"

I add Blog posting on category, because each category get lot of content with a structured texte of ~2000 words (with h2, h3, images, links).
So those page aren't only a collection.
What do you think?

Comment: @jd440: You mean information about the category? You can either provide this on `CollectionPage`, or on `ItemList`, or maybe on another suitable type. But using `BlogPosting` for a category is not correct, as the category is not a blog post, right?